# How do you document a custom action using WiX?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, custom-action

The intended behavior of each custom action must be documented for the **Windows logo program**.

In **InstallShield**, custom actions are documented using the ISCustomActionReference table.

I am now using **WiX** to create my installs,  how should custom actions be documented using WiX?

Comment: Great question, it would be interesting to hear what the Wix coders have to say about this. Perhaps this is already in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason you can't do the same - you can create a custom table in the MSI file with WiX and add your docs there. The docs typically emphasize custom tables to be used as data for custom actions, so maybe they're harder to find. There's an example here of a custom table WiX element if you scroll down:

[How Best to Define a Custom Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128279/how-best-to-define-a-custom-action-in-wix)